# Prompting user for information in an Async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this piece of code that I’m working with and I ran into some questions regarding the use of async and await. I have previously made a method for closing a “project” and I use it asynchronously with an asynchronous Delegate which works great. I have also created a `deserializeAsync()` method for use in other situations that also works as advertised. However, I now want to implement an Open Project functionality for my app. I started out writing the method with the Async helper methods that I’ve used in the other delegates but I realized that I don’t know if this is an ok solution when I need to prompt the user for information by a file browsing dialog.  Showing the file browsing dialog will freeze the execution of the method and I suppose that it is therefore not asynchronous anymore. What is the best practise here? Should I `.Wait()` my asynchronous methods like this:

```
CloseProjectAsync().Wait();
```

and just let the Open Project method execute everything synchronously or would I be better of awaiting the Async methods I do have and make this method “as async as possible”?

```
private async Task OpenProjectAsync()
{
    //get folderPath
    if (m_OpenFileService.ShowDialog(null) != true)
       return;

    await CloseProjectAsync();

    await Task.Run(() => {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(m_OpenFileService.FileName);
    });

    await DeserializeAsync(something);
}
```

Comment: There are file IO methods that are already async, you don't need to  (and shouldn't) start a new thread pool thread and run blocking IO methods for file IO.

Answer (score 1):

I would make everything `async`. Modal dialogs are a bit wonky; they actually execute a nested message loop inside the blocking call. This keeps your UI and other asynchronous operations responsive, but can cause re-entrancy issues. But it's a better option than `Wait`.

If you do try to use `Wait`, you'll quickly run into the [deadlock problem I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).